# How to iterate over an array to another combination of results in typescript react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following json content and I need to extract the counties and list out the individual counties and the mapcolor

```json
{
  "state": "Area1",
  "counties": [
    "County1",
    "County2",
  ],
  "mapColor": "Yellow"
},
{
  "wda": "Area2",
  "counties": [
    "County3",
    "County4",
  ],
  "mapColor": "Green"
},
{
  "wda": "Area3",
  "counties": [
    "County5",
    "County6",
  ],
  "mapColor": "Brown"
},
```

Expected answer

```
{ "County1",  "mapColor": "Green" }
```

How can I have this result?

Answer (score 1):

You can build up a list like you're looking for by looping through the list and building up your expected list as you go. Here is an example that doesn't format the json exactly how you're wanting, since we would need a key value for the county, (alternatively you could format each new "entry" as a list with the county name and an object for the color).

```
let formatted = [];
list.forEach(entry => {
    entry.counties.forEach(county => {
        formatted.push({ county: county, "mapColor": entry.mapColor})
    });
});
return formatted;
```

The output from this would then be the following:

```
[{"county": "County1", "mapColor": "yellow"}, {"county": "County2", "mapColor":"yellow"}, ...]
```

Comment: You can swap `map()` out for another `forEach()` since you're not returning anything from the `map()`